# How to add background image to an tkinter application?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, label

I recently made a Python watch application. But it looks very boring because of the one-color background and just nothing except of the time and the date. So I wanted to add background to the application. And I ran into a problem: If I just pack the image into a label, the other labels won't be transparent and will have their own background. I tried to use `tkinter.Canvas`, but it doesn't work with labels. Any suggestions?

That's the code for the first version of the app:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from random import choice
import datetime

root=Tk()
BGCOLOR='#000000'
FGCOLOR='#FFFFFF'
root.overrideredirect(True)
w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
h = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(str(w)+'x'+str(h)+'+0+0')
root.configure(bg=BGCOLOR)

date=str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0].split('-')
tl=Label(root,text=str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[1].split('.')[0],font=['URW Gothic L',300], fg=FGCOLOR, bg=BGCOLOR)
dl=Label(root,text=date[2]+'.'+date[1]+'.'+date[0],font=['URW Gothic L',100],bg=BGCOLOR,fg=FGCOLOR)

tl.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
dl.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)

Button(master=root,text='X',bg=BGCOLOR,fg=FGCOLOR,command=root.destroy).pack(side=RIGHT)

while True:
    tl.config(text=str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[1].split('.')[0])
    if date!=str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0].split('-'):
        date=str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0].split('-')
        dl.config(text=date[2]+'.'+date[1]+'.'+date[0])
        dl.update()
    tl.update()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: no, doesn't work. I watched in `tk.Tk().config()` (without arguments it prints out the actual configuration) and there is no parameter called 'image'

Comment: Check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-images-as-backgrounds-in-tkinter/

Comment: did I. but it doesn't work for Label classes

Comment: Oh well, I found it. But... I can't choose foreground color, can I?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution itself is, to create a Canvas object and use create_text() function with "fill" and "font" arguments. The best thing about this is that you can change the position of the text